# R operation without for loop

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

I have an index data frame which have index$row and index$col columns which indicate row and columns of X data frame.

index data frame

```
row col
375  1
376  1
379  1
380  1
381  1
460  4
461  4
462  4
463  4
```

I want to take the minimum values of each observation in X data frame, which is indicated by index data frame.

How can I do it without using a for loop?
I need this because i have more than one index data frame and this takes very much time with for loop.

Answer (score 1):

We can convert the 'index' to `matrix` (assuming 'index' is `data.frame`) and extract the values of the minimum values from the 'X' dataset using the row/column indexing provided by 'index'.  The code is below

```
X{as.matrix(index)]
```

Comment: I didn't downvote but there is a typo - curly bracket instead of square bracket.